# У меня есть проблема

Tags: грамматика, стилистика

Суть проблемы: читаю предложения, после переписываю по памяти, а затем проверяю и сравниваю написанное из текста со своим текстом. Выходят такие ошибки, где у меня не правильно было “склонено” слово - неправильно поставлено окончание.

Вот несколько примеров (Мастер и Маргарита): “...Вода в пруде почернела, и легкая лодочка уже скользила
по ней, и слышался плеск весла и смешки какой-то гражданки (А я пишу - гражданкЕ)”
в лодочке.”

2) “...И на балконе был у Понтия Пилата, и в саду, когда он с Каифой (А я пишу - с КаифОМ) разговаривал, и на помосте, но только тайно, инкогнито, так сказать, так что прошу вас – никому ни слова и полный секрет!.. Тсс!”

3) “...Да, действительно, объяснилось все: и страннейший завтрак у покойного философа Канта, и дурацкие речи про подсолнечное масло и Аннушку, и предсказания о том, что голова будет отрублена, и все прочее – профессор был сумасшедший. (Пишу - сумасшедшИМ)”

4) “...Берлиоз тотчас сообразил, что следует делать. Откинувшись на спинку скамьи, он за спиною (Пишу - за спинОЮ) профессора замигал Бездомному, - не противоречь, мол, ему, - но растерявшийся поэт этих сигналов не понял.”
И еще несколько коротких:

“...Тут у самого выхода на Бронную со скамейки навстречу редактору (А я - редакторА) поднялся в точности тот…

“...бешеным движением в тот же миг подтянув ноги к животу, и, повернувшись, разглядел несущееся (несущеЙСЯ) на него с неудержимой силой совершенно белое от ужаса лицо женщины-вагоновожатой…”

Как мне решить эту проблему, что мне стоит подучить, или что выучить, какие правила распространяются по таким случаем. Могли бы вы как можно яснее все это объяснить, в какие дебри русского языка я должен окунуться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эльгар, к сожалению, Вы не написали, русский - Ваш родной язык или нет.
Вы не отслеживаете связь слов в предложении и используете не тот падеж. Вот это и подучите.

(1) Смешки (кого?  - требуется родительный падеж) гражданки.

(2) Каифа - имя, склоняется как существительное первого склонения: (с кем? ) с Каифой.

(3) Был сумасшедший и был сумасшедшим - оба варианта допустимы.

(4) (Пишу - за спинОЮ) - правильно пишете.

(5) Навстречу (кому? - требуется дательный падеж) редактору

(6) Лицо (какое?) несущееся.